# Spring Framework integration testing with overriding DAO class

Tags: java, spring, testing, integration-testing

Im setting up integration tests in Spring to test if my API endpoints are working correctly.
There is no code because the question is a design problem question.

Right now i have a specific DAO class that talks to a real DB for IO operations.

I have a naive implementation of in-memory resource storage for testing that does not need any DB set up.

My question is how should I configure my tests in Spring so that the resource storing is done by the in-memory storage implementation.
(I need to mock the http requests and assert that they work properly, right now a test is up and running but the resource storing is done on the real db using the DAO for that)

P.S. i can replace the real db in the application.properties to a H2 db which would work with the current DAO, but i dont need that change to be in the DB layer, i need it to be in the DAO layer, to use a different implementation of resource storage class.

I'm relatively new to Spring testing, and i'm using jUnit for testing.

Thank you very much. All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to override beans in tests (use another implementation), you can create yet another Spring context (in test classes or resources) where you create beans with the *same IDs*.

If you use XML - that would be enough, just put the contexts in the right order when declaring them in test. If you use Java configuration - you may want to ensure that the test implementation is used by marking the fake bean as `@Primary`